# How to call function from resolve?

Tags: angularjs

I have been struggling with resolving in AngularJS. I wanted to load custom components and then call their functions but haven't managed to find a way.

In the below code I have tried to display SweetAlert (http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) once the item has been successfully posted.

function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index/main");

```
$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
    // Set to true if you want to see what and when is dynamically loaded
    debug: false
});
$stateProvider

    ....
    .state('index.item', {
        url: "/:itemId/edit",
        templateUrl: "views/item-edit.html",
        data: {pageTitle: 'Edit Item'},
        controller: function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, $rootScope, $state, $modal, $log, $ocLazyLoad) {
            //console.log($routeParams.itemId);

            var demo1 = function () {
                SweetAlert.swal({
                    title: "Welcome in Alerts",
                    text: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text of the printing and typesetting industry."
                });
            }

            $scope.updateItem = function() {
                $log.log('Submiting item info');
                $http.post('/api/item', $scope.item)
                    .success(function(data) {
                        demo1();
                    })
                    .error(function(data) {
                        console.log('Error: ' + data);
                    });
            }
        },
        resolve: {
            loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                    {
                        files: ['js/plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js', 'css/plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.css']
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'oitozero.ngSweetAlert',
                        files: ['js/plugins/sweetalert/angular-sweetalert.min.js']
                    }
                ]);
            }
        }
    })
```

While trying to use the code above, I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: SweetAlert is not defined
    at demo1 (config.js:156)
    at config.js:170
    at angular.js:9354
    at angular.js:13168
    at l.$eval (angular.js:14381)
    at l.$digest (angular.js:14197)
    at l.$apply (angular.js:14486)
    at l (angular.js:9644)
    at O (angular.js:9834)
    at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (angular.js:9775)
```

and the main reason is probably the property loadPlugin which is not called anywhere inside the controller. Does Anyone know how to modify the code in order to load the defined plugins and use them inside the controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is explicitly written in your error.

**`SweetAlert is not defined`**

Meaning that in your controller you forgot to add `SweetAlert` to your dependencies.

just add SweetAlert to the end of your conrtoller line:

```
controller: function ($scope, ... $ocLazyLoad, SweetAlert) {
```

Comment: I can see that. What I don't know is how to load the files which contain the definition of SweetAlert.

Comment: @NikoGamulin added an example.